# Skylake Intel Chromebook no audio only shows hdmi as output

Tags: drivers, sound, hdmi, chromebook

I am newbie, but after a few days of research i can't seem to fix this issue. i install xbuntu on lenovo chromebook. Was working fine but can't get the audio to work. after checking i notice the only output was the hdmi. I have can't seem get xbuntu to identify or put the right driver on to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Install "pavucontrol", open it, go to the "Configuration" tab and under "Built-In Audio" try selecting something along the lines of "Analog Stereo Duplex", or just try stuff until something works.

I am no expert, though, and this will basically disable audio through your HDMI port. I just installed Xubuntu on a Dell Inspiron, and this fixed my issue. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also own a Lenovo Chromebook 13, and have installed Linux (in my case Manjaro I3wm). Unfortunately, I think you're probably out of luck here until a driver is written for this hardware. I've tried replacing my Linux kernel all the way up to 4.10, and still no dice. If your hellbent on this device, and using a full fledged Linux distro, than your best bet (at least in the interim) will be a USB audio device, or a usb-c to headphone jack adapter.